# Kotlin: Ktor how to respond text as html

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to use library `kotlin-html` to produce html instead of kotlinx.html. 
This library produces just a html-text:

```
p("A paragraph").render()
// => <p>A paragraph</p>
```

but I can't find how to respond html instead of text using Ktor

```
fun Routing.root() {
    get("/") {
        call.respondText {"<p>A paragraph</p>"}
    }
}
```

This code will produce a page with text `<p>A paragraph</p>` instead of html-page. And it seems that `call.respondHtml` only works with kotlinx.html DSL. How can I do this using plain text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify `ContentType.Text.Html` for the `ContentType` parameter to `respondText`

```
call.respondText("<p>foo</p>", ContentType.Text.Html)
```

`ContentType.Text.Plain` is used by default if no `ContentType` if provided.

Answer (score 4):

Ktor has a special module for working with `kotlinx.html`, so you can use

```
call.respondHtml {
    head {
        title { +"Async World" }
    }
    body {
        h1(id = "title") {
            +"Title"
        }
    }
}
```

See details here: https://ktor.io/servers/features/templates/html-dsl.html

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your question. But let an answer be here for someone searching…

Comment: it doesnt work for me. Got an error. "Cannot find a parameter with this name: id.

What is id? A variable which i have to implement first?